# Combining weighted overlay map with exclusion map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, weighted-overlay

[image][image]I use ArcMap and I've made a weighted overlay map and up to these map I want to add a map which contains excluded areas. My intention is to create a map similar to the weighted one but upon this, the excluded areas would have replaced the areas of the weighted (with another colour, obviously).

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a sample image of your output and input maps